# Rate of convergence for difference between conditional and marginal probability

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, asymptotics, binomial-distribution, research

Suppose $X\sim \text{Bin}(2n,p)$ and $X_1,X_2\sim\text{Bin}(n,p)$ are independent, with $X_1+X_2=X$. I'm interested in the rate of convergence for the absolute difference
$$
\left\vert P(X>c|X_1\leq a,X_2\leq a)-P(X>c)\right\vert
$$
where $a$ and $c$ are constants in a neighborhood of $np$ and $2np$, respectively. Specifically, $a\in[np,np+o(n^{2/3})]$, and $c\in[2np,2a)$. These ranges will help control the rate of convergence. Assume that the conditioning set has probability 1 asymptotically.

The reason I'm interested in bounding the quantity above is because I need to approximate the conditional probability with the normal tail probability (e.g. by Berry-Esseen bound).

**Question**
Are there any references for this result? I've tried writing out the probabilities explicitly, but can't seem to get anywhere with the calculations.

**Edit**
By some elementary probability, I can show that on one hand
$$
P(X>c|X_1\leq a,X_2\leq a)=\frac{P(X>c,X_1\leq a,X_2\leq a)}{P(X_1\leq a,X_2\leq a)}\leq \frac{P(X>c)}{P(X_1\leq a,X_2\leq a)}\leq P(X>c)(1+o(1)) 
$$
where $o(1)$ is the rate as $n\to\infty$.
On the other hand,
\begin{align*}
P(X>c\mid X_1\leq a,X_2\leq a)&=\frac{P(X>c,X_1\leq a,X_2\leq a)}{P(X_1\leq a,X_2\leq a)}\\
&= \frac{P(X>c)}{P(X_1\leq a,X_2\leq a)}- \frac{P(X>c,\{X_1> a\}\cup\{X_2> a\})}{P(X_1\leq a,X_2\leq a)}\\
&\geq P(X>c)- \frac{P(X>c,\{X_1> a\}\cup\{X_2> a\})}{P(X_1\leq a,X_2\leq a)}\\
&\geq P(X>c)(1-o(1))
\end{align*}
where I claim that $P(X>c,\{X_1> a\}\cup\{X_2> a\})/P(X_1\leq a,X_2\leq a)=o(P(X>c))$.

This suggests the stronger result that 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{P(X>c\mid X_1\leq a,X_2\leq a)}{P(X>c)}=1
$$

Is the work above correct? Have I missed something or been careless about the convergence rates $1\pm o(1)$?

Comment: Your calculation cannot be correct because you don't use that $c<2a$. And it seems natural that $\mathbb{P}(X>c|X_1\leq a,X_2\leq a)\ll \mathbb{P}(X>c)  $ if $c-2a$ is too small. Therefore I think you should give a more precise hypothesis on $a$ and $c$.

Comment: @RaphaelB4 I don't think that $c<2a$ is needed to make the calculations go through. Further, I think that this will work for any $c<2a$. The event $\{X_1\leq a,X_2\leq a\}$ happens with high probability as $n\to\infty$, so that I think even if $c-2a$ is small, the conditional and marginal should be asymptotically the same.